# 500 error: null value in column "timeline_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I'm currently a student and am trying to create a full stack web application with python/django and React. While building my back-end I have run into a problem where, when posting an object containing an association, the association's id is lost between the response payload and the database. I know that the state is updating as it should and that other objects that don't use associations on the back-end can be created without a problem. I assume my mistake has to be somewhere in the models or serializers that I made, but so far I haven't found it.

500 error message:

```
Integrity error at "api/v1/event"
null value in column "timeline_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL: failing row contains (index_id, junk_data, junk_data, 1, null)
```

my models:

```
from django.db import models

class Timeline(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='n/a')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='n/a')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='n/a')
    coordinate = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    timeline = models.ForeignKey(Timeline, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="events")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Note(models.Model):
    article = models.TextField(default='n/a')
    event  = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='notes')
    # event = models.ManyToManyField(Event)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.article
```

my views:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

from .serializers import TimelineSerializer, EventSerializer, NoteSerializer
from .models import Timeline, Event, Note

class TimelineView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Timeline.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TimelineSerializer

class EventView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Event.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EventSerializer

class NoteView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Note.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NoteSerializer
```

my serializers:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Timeline, Note, Event

class NoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'article')


class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    notes = NoteSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'coordinate', 'notes')


class TimelineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    events = EventSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Timeline
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'events')
```

Link to the github repo:
https://github.com/dantehollo/world_builder_site

I am using python 3.6.8 on linux (ubuntu 18.04.3)

I tried to be as specific and brief as possible. If there is something missing let me know and I will post it as soon as I see the request. Any help with what this is, why it happened and how to avoid it again is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Hi, maybe this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41831521/violation-not-null-constraint-with-a-foreighkey-not-user-while-trying-to-post) can help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your `Event` model `timeline` attribute (which is also a foreign key) is required and can not be null. And you forgot to add this `timeline` into fields of EventSerializer:

```py
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    notes = NoteSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'coordinate', 'notes', 'timeline')
```

Now if you do not send `timeline` in the request, DRF will give ValidationError that you have to include it.